# Datastore One-to-Many Google App Engine

Tags: python, angularjs, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm struggling to display my array items  in the template. Just started with Entity relationships in GAE and I'm not finding suitable solutions on SO. Do i have to perform a query first in my handler. if so, how coz I'm struggling with the logic.

**Datastore** `Project` entities example display

[image]

**Datastore** `Employees` entities example display

[image]

**Project.py**

```
class Project(ndb.Model):
    projectID = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    startAt = ndb.DateTimeProperty(indexed=True)
    endAt = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
    isFullDay = ndb.BooleanProperty()
    days = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='CompanyDay', repeated=True)
    employees = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Employees', repeated=True)
    client = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='Client')

class Employees(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    role = ndb.StringProperty()
```

**template**

**`data`** is fetched from the backend through angular's **`http`** service

```
 <md-content  class="md-padding projects" layout="row" layout-wrap>
        <md-card ng-repeat="data in controller.projects" flex="20" ng-click="editProject(data)">
            <img src="" alt="">
            <md-card-content>
                <div class="project-info">
                    <h2 class="md-title">{{ data.title }}</h2>
                    <p>{{ data.description }}</p>
                    <p>{{ data.employees }}</p>

                </div>
            </md-card-content>
        </md-card>
    </md-content>
```

**python code that responds to /comments**

```
class commentsJsonHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
@classmethod
def route(cls):
    """
    name: index, template: /
    """
    return webapp2.Route('/comments', handler=cls, name='_commments_')

def get(self):  
    projects = Project.query()

    def date_handler(obj):
        print obj
        if isinstance(obj, datetime):
            return obj.isoformat()
        else:
            return str(obj)

    self.response.out.write(json.dumps([dict(proj.to_dict(), **dict(id=proj.key.id())) for proj in projects], default=date_handler))
```

**from angular - code that requests from server**

```
    var vm = this;
    vm.projects = [];
    $http.get('/comments')
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            vm.projects = result.data;
         });
```

Displaying employees as from the datastore.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code.

Comment: Plus, you need to actually post the code that is retrieving the data.

Comment: Edited post to include server-fetching-code in angular.

Comment: And what is the Python code that responds to /comments?

Comment: included now in edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change your date_handler to handle ndb.Key to properly render your Employee collection in your returned json

```
def date_handler(obj):
    print obj
    if isinstance(obj, datetime):
        return obj.isoformat()
    elif isinstance(obj, ndb.Key):
      return obj.get().to_dict()
    else:
        return str(obj)
```

You may want to change the name of this method as it is not  just doing date_handling any more